# PowerShell - have trouble using the Count method

Tags: powershell

I have the following code (thanks to input from 'jon Z' and 'manojlds') that processes server lists, checks the error logs for each server against a search string, and then sends an email report listing the servers with bad error logs and good error logs.

What I would like to do now is do a **count** of the number of servers with bad error logs and good error logs and put that info in the email report as well.

I would have something like this in each heading of my email report:

**The following *n* servers have bad error logs:**

**The following *n* servers are OK:**

I've been trying to accomplish this by using the `Count` method, but have so far been unsuccessful. Is the `Count` method the correct approach? Is so, how (where would I apply it in my code)? If not, then what is the best approach?

Code:

```
$BadServerLogs = "<font style=`"font-family:verdana;font-size:9pt`"><p><b>The following servers have bad error logs:</b></p>"
$GoodServerLogs = "<font style=`"font-family:verdana;font-size:9pt`"><p><b>The following servers are OK:</b></p>"

# Use hash table to associate server list to search string array
$Groups = @{
$SERVER_LST_1=$SEARCH_STR_ARRAY_1;
$SERVER_LST_2=$SEARCH_STR_ARRAY_2;
$SERVER_LST_3=$SEARCH_STR_ARRAY_3;
$SERVER_LST_4=$SEARCH_STR_ARRAY_4;
}
$StartupErrors = @{}
$Groups.keys | %{
$key = $_
gc $key | %{
    # Check StartupError.log files for errors
    $StartupErrors[$_] = Get-ChildItem -Path \\$_\$LOG_PATH -Include StartupError.log -Recurse | Select-String -notmatch $Groups["$key"]
    If ($StartupErrors[$_])
    {
        $Subject = "StartupError Logs Report: BAD ERROR LOGS!"
        $BadServerLogs += "<li><a href=`"\\$_\$LOG_PATH\StartupError.log`">$_</a></li>"
    }
    Else 
    { 
        $Subject = "StartupError Logs Report: All Logs are Fine"
        $GoodServerLogs += "<li>$_</li>" 
    }
}   
}
# Send email listing servers with bad/good StartupError log files
Send-MailMessage -Body "$BadServerLogs $GoodServerLogs" -BodyAsHtml -Subject $Subject -SmtpServer $SmtpServer -To $MailTo -From $MailFrom
```

Thanks in advance! -Keith

Comment: I don't see `count` in there anywhere?

Comment: I think he's asking where it would go...  The first two lines are where you need the count, but you don't know the count yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just create two variables:

```
$goodCount = 0
$badCount = 0
```

Then in the loop increment each depending on the case:

```
If ($StartupErrors[$_])
{
    $Subject = "StartupError Logs Report: BAD ERROR LOGS!"
    $BadServerLogs += "<li><a href=`"\\$_\$LOG_PATH\StartupError.log`">$_</a></li>"
    $badCount += 1
}
Else 
{ 
    $Subject = "StartupError Logs Report: All Logs are Fine"
    $GoodServerLogs += "<li>$_</li>"
    $goodCount += 1
}
```

Then create some HTML and send it:

```
$html = "<h1>The following $badCount servers have bad error logs:</h1>" + $BadServerLogs
$html += "<h1>The following $goodCount servers are OK:</h1>" + $GoodServerLogs

Send-MailMessage -Body $html -BodyAsHtml -Subject $Subject -SmtpServer $SmtpServer -To $MailTo -From $MailFrom
```